# Symfony 2.7 + Sass + Assetic does not create any styles or files

Tags: css, symfony, sass, compass-sass, assetic

I would like to use `Sass` based styles in my Symfony 2.7 WebApp. So far I have used `Compass` to compile Sass files (located not in the `web/` dir but within the Bundles) to CSS files. This works fine, but on a new server Ruby is not available and thus Compass is not an option anymore.

Following the [Symfony Docu](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/assetic/php.html), I have added leafo/scssphp to the project and activated in the config file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    filters:
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
        # ...
```

The Sass files within the `Twig` templates:

```
{% stylesheets 
    'MyMainBundle/Resources/styles/sass/header.scss'
    filter="scssphp" 
    output="css/header.css" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

When using the debug front controller `app_dev.php` a page refresh shows, that the `header.css` is correctly link, **but the linked file is empty**.

The `header.scss` contains **pure Sass** (no Compass function), the path is correct and **no error is displayed**. So, why is the `header.css` empty?

Dumping the assets instead of using `app_dev.php` does not solve the problem as well. The console shows all assets that are created during the dump, but not any sign of the `header.css`

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

I tried different other possibilits to specifiy the path of the `header.scss`, but the result is always the same. Only using the @Bundle notation results in an NotFoundException.

```
{% stylesheets 
    '@MyMainBundle/Resources/sass/header.scss'
    ...
```

It does not make any difference if the Sass files are located inside a bundle directory or inside the `web/` folder (as described in the Symfony docs).

**So: How to integrate the Sass file directly into Symfony by using Assetic?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Maybe the solution is useful for others as well:

My AsseticBundle / Assetic version was outdated. After updated to the latest version everything works fine.